# R, dplyr, %in% operator

Tags: r, dplyr

I create a one variable dataframe with:

(1)  `q <- jc2a %>% filter(lvl == "57") %>% select(prev_job) %>% distinct`

I then produce a table, looking for counts for records with prev_job in the q dataframe:

(2)  `table(jc2a %>% filter(prev_job %in% q$prev_job) %>% select(sex))`

Can I put (1) into (2), and do it in one statement?

I tried:

(3)

```
table(jc2a %>% filter(prev_job %in% (jc2a %>% filter(lvl == "57") %>% 
    select(prev_job) %>% distinct)) %>% select(sex))
```

which produced the error:

Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `%in%` like a "normal" function by backticking it like `\`%in%\`(x, table)`

Comment: i imagine you'd have to use something dumb like `is_in` because magrittr

Comment: Tried Scriven's backtick -- filter(`%in%`(prev_job, jc2a %>% filter(lvl == "57"), but same error.

Comment: I am sorry but it is very hard to read the code and imagine the output. Could you please provide the code using one of the built-in R data sets like `iris` or `mtcars` in order to allow us to better understand your goal.

Comment: `table` is going to return something besides a `data.frame`-like object. `select` is only going to work with a `data.frame`-like object. Why aren't you using `count`?

Comment: table is an unnecessary complication as @hrbrmstr points out  jc2a %>% filter(prev_job %in% q$prev_job) %>% count(sex)